# Show that $x^p - m$ is irreducible for prime $p$ and $m \in \mathbb{Q^{\times}}\setminus \left(\mathbb{Q^{\times}}\right)^p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm stuck if $m$ is not a prime or has a single prime divider (Then using Eisenstein's criterion), e.g, $m=4$ and $p=5$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think we have a perfect duplicate somewhere. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/403924/11619) is the best match I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^p-m=A(x)B(x)$ with $\deg(A)=a$ and $\deg(B)=b$, then $|A(0)|=|m|^{a/m}$ and $|B(0)|=|m|^{b/m}$ (using roots-coefficients relations). This should lead to a contradiction when you decompose $m$ in prime factors.